# Extracting .NET Resources to a File

Tags: .net, resources

I need to extract the resources from a .NET application to a location on my hard drive. How can I do this?

eg. 
I have a exe file in my c# resources and i want to copy the resource file to my harddrive programaticaly.

Comment: And what is your question? Me too I need many things.

Comment: Be more specific about what you need.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to extract embedded resources from a compiled assembly to a location on your local disk?

Comment: why u people closed my question. read i have modified it

Comment: @Krish, do you mean you want to take the `.resx` file from inside the assembly and get out the information contained within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a resource stream and copy it's content to a FileStream.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292 might be what you want

Comment: I needed it in c# programaticaly